# loop in executeUpdate (java application, oracle)

Tags: java, oracle

Good night guys. 
I'm doing a java applet to handle that uses the database, in times of insertion works right, the problem is in the update and delete the executeUpdate  loops.
for example, if I try to insert the following code by java will not. Now the cmd will.

```
UPDATE CIDADE SET  NOME_CIDADE = 'Alegre', UF = 'ES' WHERE CODCIDADE = '4'
```

My class connection to the database is as follows:

```
package gbd1.util.conexoes;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConexaoOracle implements IConexoes {

    private Connection con;
    private String nomeUsuario;
    private String senha;
    private String database;
    private  PreparedStatement ps = null;
    private Statement stat = null;

    @Override
    public Connection IniciarConexao(String database, String usuario, String senha) throws SQLException {

        this.database = database;
        this.nomeUsuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE", "Paula", "2011204415");
            stat = con.createStatement();
            return con;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public ResultSet querySelect(String sql) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        return rs;
    }

    public int updadeBanco(String sql) throws SQLException { 
        stat = con.createStatement();
        int i = stat.executeUpdate(sql);

        return i;
    }
}
```

This is the where clase call the executeUpdate..

```
public class RecuperacaoDados {
    private static IConexoes conexao;

    public static void recuperar(String sgbd, String nomeBd, String nomeUsuario, String senha) throws Exception{

        //conexao = CriarConexao.create(sgbd);
        conexao = new ConexaoOracle();
        conexao.IniciarConexao("", "", "");
        //---------------------------------------
        LogsCollection logs = LogsCollection.getLogs(null);
        String query;
        String atri;
        String valu;
        int i, j=0;
        for (Log l:logs.getLogs()){
            query ="";
            atri="";
            valu="";
            j=0;
            System.out.println(l.getOperacao());
            if(l.getOperacao().equalsIgnoreCase("INSERT")){
                query= "INSERT INTO "+ l.getNomeTabela();
                i = l.getAtributos().size();
                for (Atributo at: l.getAtributos()){
                    if( (j!=0)){
                        atri=atri+", ";
                        valu=valu+", ";
                    }
                    atri=atri+at.getNomeAtributo();
                    valu=valu+"'"+at.getValorAtributo()+"'";
                    j++;
                }
                query = query + " ("+ atri + ") VALUES ("+valu+ ")";
                System.out.println(query);
                conexao.updadeBanco(query);
            }
            else if(l.getOperacao().equalsIgnoreCase("UPDATE")){
                query= "UPDATE "+ l.getNomeTabela()+ " SET " ;
                i = l.getAtributos().size();
                for (Atributo at: l.getAtributos()){
                    if( (j!=0)){
                        query=query+ ", ";
                    }
                    query = query+ at.getNomeAtributo()+" = '"+ at.getValorAtributo()+"'";
                    j++;
                }
                query = query + " WHERE ";
                j=0;
                for ( ChavePrimaria at: l.getPks()){
                    if( (j!=0)){
                        query=query+ " AND ";
                    }
                    query = query+ at.getNome()+" = "+ at.getValor()+"";
                    //  atri=atri+at.getNomeAtributo();
                    // valu=valu+"'"+at.getValorAtributo()+"'";
                    j++;
                }

                // query = query + " ("+ atri + ") VALUES ("+valu+ ")";

                query = "DELETE CIDADE  WHERE CODCIDADE = 2";
                System.out.println(query);
                conexao.updadeBanco(query);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I put the query as "default" for testing...

Can anyone help me?

update: 
I found it was error on the drive.

Comment: What is the error you get? or does the update simply doesn't work?

Comment: simply does nothing, loops and does not notify me of any errors.

Comment: Loops? how do you know that it is looping? do you see anything in the Applet console?

Comment: I suppose it's a loop, why not just do nothing.

Comment: Can you run this in cmd and see whether it returns any results? SELECT * FROM CIDADE WHERE CODCIDADE = '4'

Comment: You're not closing neither the result set nor the connection. You should start there.

Comment: When I run the select, the following output appears: _ CODCIDADE NOME_CIDADE                                                                                          UF
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --
         4 Dores do Rio Preto                                                                                   ES _

Comment: It could help that you post the code where you're instantiating/using the ConexaoOracle class.

Comment: Ready @ra2085, put...

Comment: Ok. you're doing a delete query, not an update. Isn't it? Three lines before conexao.updadeBanco(query) you're overriding all your dynamic query algorithm with a delete query. It's that the way its supposed to be working or you were just testing it?

Comment: Paula @ra285 is correct. you are overriding the query.

Comment: I'm just testing, when I tried the right way, with the update, it would be right at that moment, I noticed the "error", so I put it to print the query, and performed similarly in cmd, and cmd was. Ai put the delete just as a test.

Comment: This is what appears in the netbeans console: 
INSERT INTO CIDADE (CODCIDADE, NOME_CIDADE, UF) VALUES ('12', 'Dores do Rio Preto', 'ES')

DELETE CIDADE WHERE (codcidade = '2')

Comment: can you update your changes so we can keep reviewing your code?

Comment: Now yes @ra2085, updated everything according to what is in my program now

Comment: could you do something like "System.err.println("Operation result code: "+conexao.updadeBanco(query));" instead of conexao.updadeBanco(query); and paste the console results.

Comment: Operation result code: UPDATE CIDADE SET CODCIDADE = '4', NOME_CIDADE = 'Vitoria', UF = 'ES' WHERE CODCIDADE = '4'

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't the return value from the updateBanco method should be an Integer?

Comment: yes I have. I do not understand what is happening. What I'm most impressed is that it rises no exception.

Comment: Sorry, can keep on going with this question. Need to sleep. Boa sorte!

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help: D And good night.